# Como puedo ver un RDD en Spark.python

Tags: python, pyspark

tengo el siguiente código, necesito eliminar la puntuación de la información obtenida en un archivo, aplico una formula para hacer el ejercicio, no me genera error, pero no he podido ver la información que quedo en el RDD, alguien me pude ayudar o indicarme como puedo ver lo que esta en  shakespeareRDD ?

lo stoy haciendo en spark phyton en la pagina de databricks

```
def removePunctuation(text):

  import re

  return re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '', text).lower().strip()


fileName = '/databricks-datasets/cs100/lab1/data-001/shakespeare.txt'


shakespeareRDD = sc.textFile(fileName)


shakespeareRDD = shakespeareRDD.map(lambda x: removePunctuation(text))
```

intente lo siguiente tambien

```
a= shakespeareRDD.collect()
b=a.map(lambda x: (a,1))
print(b)
```

y esto

```
a= shakespeareRDD.collect()
print(a)
```

y esto

```
print(shakespeareRDD.collect)
```

y esto

```
print(shakespeareRDD.collect)
```

resultado:`bound method RDD.collect of PythonRDD[3] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:59`

pero en ningun caso pude ver lo que quedo en la variable shakespeareRDD para ver si lo que hice esta bien.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola para saber con exactitud deberiamos ver que version de python esta utilizando y que version de spark.

Puedo suponer que debe estar utilizando 2.6, porque tiene un detalle:

`print` no es una función en Python 2.6.

Puede hacer lo siguiente, probar hacer un metodo que dentro haga el print ejemplo :

```
 from operator import add

    def imprimir(x):
       print x  
   shakespeareRDD.collect().foreach(imprimir)
```

o

```
from __future__ import print_function
   shakespeareRDD.collect().foreach(print)
```

O bien recomiendo usar el for de la siguiente forma

```
for x in shakespeareRDD.collect():
     print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir el contenido de un RDD es habitual usar `.take(n)` siendo 'n' el número de valores del RDD que se quieren mostrar.

Ejemplo usando spark 2.4.5 en Jupyter:

```
rdd_diccionario.take(3)
```

resultado:

```
[(1.68, 'abandonado'), (3.18, 'abejas'), (2.8, 'aborto')]
```